# Puncture in SCHWALBE CITIZEN ACTIVE tire

Tags: tire, puncture

Does anybody know what type of tire is SCHWALBE CITIZEN ACTIVE? I have a tiny punctures in it and have no idea how to fix. May be I wrong but I think it is tubeless. Should I bring it to service or is it possible to fix myself?

Update: Tyre is attached to rim with some tape. Image below
[image]

Comment: Unless you were given a little bottle of sealant when you bought it -- and you've been adding sealant every six months -- it's unlikely that it's tubeless.

Comment: Fixing a puncture is easy -- but it's best to look over someone's shoulder the first time you do it. Have you bike shop do it this time (5-15 eurodollars) and ask if you can watch. Many bike stores also offer basic maintenance classes.

Comment: That is rim tape.  It is not attacked to the tire.   How would you get inside a tire to tape it?

Comment: You absolutely right. It wasn't attached, I didn't get it from first glance. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A quick google shows https://www.schwalbe.com/en/tour-reader/citizen.html

Its a straightforward clincher tyre that may be used tubeless, but may be used with a tube.

Best thing to do is take the tyre off and see if there's a tube inside.

Do note that tubeless tyres can be run with tubes perfectly well.

[image: From https://www.schwalbe.com/en/tour-reader/citizen.html]

From there, your question devolves to either :

[how to fix a puncture in a tubeless tyre](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/how-do-you-fix-a-puncture-on-tubeless-tires)  or

[to patch or replace a tube?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/patch-or-replace-tube)  followed by either: [how to fix a puncture in a tube tyre](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13007/what-steps-should-i-follow-to-patch-a-tube)  or  [how to replace a tube in a tyre](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-i-fix-a-puncture/)

Comment: I was trying to take it off but found that it is glued with some kind of tape. Also when I bought the bicycle I haven't got any sealant.

Comment: I was trying to google about different kind of tyre repairs but haven't seen in any video that a tire is glued with tape

Comment: Added picture to the post

Comment: That tape is there to cover where the spokes attach to the rim so that the sharp edges to not puncture the inner tube. I would also look up a YouTube video on basic tire and tube removal and replacement.